# Как вывести элемент ассоциативного массива внутри двойных кавычек?

Tags: php

```
$arr = ['foo' => 'bar'];
echo "$arr['foo']"; // Ошибка!
```

PS Числовой массив не подходит.
PPS `$arr[foo];` - так вроде плохо делать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно делаю так

```
$arr = array('foo' => 'bar'); // в php так массивы пишутся
echo "какой-то текст {$arr['foo']} и тут тоже";
```

или же

```
echo "какой-то текст " . $arr['foo'] . " и тут тоже";
```

Comment: Сложный синтаксис! Про него то я и забыл. Спасибо!

Comment: На здоровье ))))